# Angular 4 Set Focus On Hidden Element

Tags: angular

I have a sidebar on a page that when I click the icon to expand the side-bar, I want to set focus on the input within that sidebar. That input is display: none before the sidebar is expanded. If I put a timeout in my code of a second, then try to set focus it works, but this is not ideal. We do not want to setTimeout. Is there something I can do?

```
<input #quickSearch id="quickSearch" type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />

@ViewChild("inputBox") inputBox: ElementRef;

expand() {
    myService.expandSidebar(); // This simply adds a class to show the sidebar
    // Only focuses if I setTimeout here. Firing changeDetection also does nothing
    inputBox.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Comment: can't you emit an event after the sidebar finishes expanding?

Answer (score 0):

I made the toggleLeft() function a promise, and set focus after the promise finished.